# XPath and Jenkins Plot plugin

Tags: xml, xpath, hudson, plot, jenkins

I'm trying to use Jenkins' Plot plugin to generate a graph of how many "TODO" markers we have in our code.

I have an XML file being generated as part of the build which includes data about them (among other things): each TODO marker has a line in the XML which looks like this:

```
<tag line="3" name="todo" description="Do something with this"/>
```

Using a stand-alone xpath tool, I can use an expression `//tag[@name='todo']` to get all the matching elements, or `count(//tag[@name='todo'])` to just get the number of them.

This count is the value I want to plot. However I've been unable to get any data onto a chart in Jenkins.

I've created the plot and specified that it's an XML file. Jenkins then asks me if the result will be a Nodeset, Node, String, Boolean or Number.

I assume "Nodeset" would be applicable to `//tag[@name='todo']` and "Number" to `count(//tag[@name='todo'])`. But I've tried them both, and both of them just give me an empty graph, with no data plotted on it.

The most frustrating thing of all is that Jenkins doesn't give me any feedback on what the problem is; just the empty graph. Nothing in the build log, or anywhere else I can see.

Can anyone help me get this working? I can't find any examples anywhere. It seems like it ought to be simple, but it's just not happening for me.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

A larger sample of the XML, as requested in the comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
  <method>
    <docblock>
      <tag line="763" name="todo" description="This needs doing"/>
    </docblock>
  </method>
  <method>
    <docblock>
      <tag line="14" name="todo" description="This also needs doing"/>
    </docblock>
  </method>
</project>
```

(I've snipped out elements and attributes that aren't relevant, but this is the basic structure)

So as far as I can tell, there isn't any XML namespacing going on there.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provide a small version of the XML document. My first suspicion is that the XML contains a default namespace.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - thanks for the comment. I've appended a sanitised sample chunk of XML to the question.

Comment: SDC, there seem to be other people getting empty results, and their questions are also unanswered -- the probable conclusion is that the XPath support in this plugin is problematic. You can contact the plugin developers via their mailing list: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Mailing+List%2C+Mailing+List

Comment: SDC, Yes, from what I read, it seems that they don't have a full XPath engine and they support only limited types of XPAth expressions, where the predicate is just a number -- such as: `/*/changeSet/item[1]/node/text()`

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - thanks for taking the time to help me. Interesting to learn that it's only a limited xpath engine; I wasn't even able to find that info (my google-fu must be weak today). Can you give me a URL where I can find that? (if you post it with your earlier comments as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted).

Comment: SDC: I didn't find any statement or descriptio of the XPath support provided. However I found only a few examples of XPath expressions that were said to be successful, and they all were of the very simple form that has a number in a predicate. Here is an URL to such evidence:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-626

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I finally achieved to make work is the following :

I generate a report file with the following datas :

```
<report>
  <serie1>10</serie1>
  <serie2>20</serie2>
  <serie3>30</serie3>
</report>
```

Then I configure my plot with the following configuration :

```
 XPath Result type : Nodeset
 XPath Expression : /report/*
```

Then I get a correct plotting of my datum : the series names are taken from the element name (serie1, serie2...) and the value is taken from the text content.
Indeed, this is what was explained in the help block :

```
 (...)
 If a nodeset is selected, a point for each node that is selected will be plotted.
 The label of each point is the name of the element that was selected, the value is the text value.
```

I don't think that this plugin is capable of taking values from XML attributes. Maybe you should consider writing a simple XSLT stylesheet which will transform your file to another one with the expected format.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for posting an answer to this question -- I had completely forgotten about the question -- it's been quite a while since I posted it. In the meanwhile, I solved the problem by using a different Jenkins plugin (the [Task Scanner plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Task+Scanner+Plugin), which counts the 'Todo' markers and produces a graph without going anywhere near my XML. Much easier; I wish I'd known about it sooner.

Comment: The Plot plugin can produce some nice charts, but it's difficult and can be boring to configure. And almost impossible if you don't have some stylesheet mechanism which is able to transform your data into a correct xml.

Comment: Answer accepted, even though I actually ended up using a completely different solution, as a thank you for taking the time to post an answer.