# Jenkins Plot plugin: How to format xml, Xpath expression to display results

Tags: xml, jenkins, xpath, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to use the Jenkins plugin plot to visualize the result of some performance tests. I am using a pipeline project, so I cannot setup the pulgin via UI. My pipeline code looks like this:

```
plot(group: 'Performance evaluation', title: 'Time taken for individual tests',
  csvFileName: 'plot_aggregated_performance_results.csv',
  xmlSeries: [[file: 'aggregated_performance_results.xml', nodeType: 'NUMBER', xpath: '/root/build', url: '']]
  style: 'line', yaxis: 'Time in sec',
  keepRecords: false)
```

The values come from an xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
<build buildnr="1">
    <test1 name="test_post_get_delete_devices">0.911048173904419</test1>
    <test2 name="test_sensor_and_actuator_value">0.7736420631408691</test2>
</build>
<build buildnr="2">
    <test1 name="test_post_get_delete_devices">0.9244387149810791</test1>
    <test2 name="test_sensor_and_actuator_value">0.8049886226654053</test2>
</build>
<build buildnr="3">
    <test1 name="test_post_get_delete_devices">0.9026336669921875</test1>
    <test2 name="test_sensor_and_actuator_value">0.8349390029907227</test2>
</build>
<build buildnr="4">
    <test1 name="test_post_get_delete_devices">1.0057721138000488</test1>
    <test2 name="test_sensor_and_actuator_value">0.9230458736419678</test2>
</build>
<build buildnr="5">
    <test1 name="test_post_get_delete_devices">0.8522133827209473</test1>
    <test2 name="test_sensor_and_actuator_value">0.7917647361755371</test2>
</build>
</root>
```

My Xpath expression is the following:

```
xpath: '/root/build'
```

I checked it with help of an online Xpath tool and it gives me the following values:

```
0.911048173904419 0.7736420631408691
0.9244387149810791 0.8049886226654053
0.9026336669921875 0.8349390029907227
1.0057721138000488 0.9230458736419678
0.8522133827209473 0.7917647361755371
```

I already had a look into: [XPath and Jenkins Plot plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941150/xpath-and-jenkins-plot-plugin) And **it seem like I have to reformat my xml file to have every value of a test in one "leafnode" of the xml and the other tests in different leafs.**

Expected output:

**So I want to show a line chart with two curves, for each test one curve or line. So each column in my xpath output represents one line.**

Am I assuming this in the correct way?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: To show a line chart with two curves, for each test one curve or line. So each column in my xpath output represents one line.